# What are the ways to listen to the success or failure of transactions when working with Spring (spring boot, spring data)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-11, spring-transactions

When working with transactions, sometimes there is a need to do an audit of working with a business object (crud operations when working with tables). At the same time, you need to do this in real time and enter this record in the database :

- the name of the user,
- the business object with which the work is performed,
- the success or rollback of the transaction with the fixing of the reason,
- the time of the event occurrence.

Share ways to solve this problem, as you do when working with Spring data.
Do you create your own custom aspects ?
Give examples, if you don't mind .

Comment: Not sure if it completely answers your question (hence I wrote it in comments) but have you checked JPA Auditing? https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

Comment: I saw. This is one of the options. If you need to separate the business object from this information ? Here you need a separate entity for auditing (a separate table). And what can be the cases of creating it : maybe a separate database and a separate microservice , if so, what is the benefit from this, if not, why ?